# Trying to install PEAR extension with composer

Tags: composer-php, pear

I'm converting an old project (with old dependencies) to manage it's dependencies using composer. The site uses PEAR's Text_Password. I read that it is possible to install dependencies with composer adding (something like) the following to composer.json:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "pear",
        "url": "http://pear.php.net"
    }
],
"require": {
    ...
    "pear-pear/Text_Password": "*"
},
```

..but I get the error:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Initializing PEAR repository http://pear.php.net
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package pear-pear/text_password could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

Is it possible to install PEAR libraries with Composer? I notice on packagist there is a collection of PEAR libraries but I couldn't see Text_Password - https://packagist.org/packages/pear/

There is also a github repo for Text_Password but I thought maybe installing direct from PEAR was better? - https://github.com/pear/Text_Password

Anyway how can I install this package with composer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "http://pear.php.net"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "pear-pear.php.net/Text_Password": "*"
    }
}
```

> **Note**: The PEAR repository has been removed from Composer 2.0

Comment: ... and what to do if we **NEED** packages in the PEAR repository??

Comment: Hmm. You could use Composer v1, or try Pear's Installer, e.g. `php pyrus.phar install pear/package_name`, or download the package archive and drop it manually into your vendor folder, or (recommended) replace the "needed" package with another package from the Composer registry. Some packages are on both registries, e.g https://github.com/pear/Structures_Graph maybe you are lucky and your PEAR package has a `composer.json`.

Comment: Sadly, in my scenario (I'm using RoundCube, the popular webmail package) it's a bit more complicated than that, because, well, on Ubuntu Linux, when integrating RoundCube with another popular mailbox manager, files are spread all over the filesystem — to deal with permissions — and it's not easy to keep *everything* updated from a single location. Also, RoundCube uses Composer v2 — no 'choice' there — and rewriting its code to figure out a different location for the PEAR packages is, well, beyond my available time...

Comment: Fortunately, in that very specific use case, the RoundCube maintainers have sort of 'annexed' the relevant packages from PEAR to their _private_ repository. This means that the only requirement is tweaking `composer.json` to use their repository instead — but I found that out only by sheer chance, and after posting my earlier comment here :-)